# Insert multiple records to BigQuery using POST api

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am trying to use the [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request#examples) python [api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/load_data_by_post.py) to load records from a JSON file. However it fails when there are multiple records in the file.

Here is how my `json` data file looks like

```
[{"queryID": "newId", "newCol": "newCol"},
 {"queryID": "newId", "newCol": "newCol"}]
```

And this is the relavent code

```
insert_request = bigquery.jobs().insert(
    projectId=project_id,
    body={
        'configuration': {
            'load': {
                'schema': {
                    'fields': simplejson.load(open(schema_path, 'r'))
                    },  
                'destinationTable': {
                    'projectId': project_id,
                    'datasetId': dataset_id,
                    'tableId': table_id
                    },  
                'sourceFormat': 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
                }   
            }   
        },  

    media_body=MediaFileUpload(
        './test_data.json',                                                                                                        
        mimetype='application/octet-stream'))

job = insert_request.execute()
```

This fails with the error `JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0 at file: file-00000000. Start of array encountered without start of object.` which I think is because it is not able to recognize it as two rows.

However if I make this only one record in my `test_data.json` file it loads successfully.

```
{"queryID": "newId", "newCol": "newCol"}
```

I have been looking at the [insert docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#insert) but not able to find an options that lets me set multiple rows for insertion.

Any body know how to load multiple records? Any leads with this is appreciated. I feel I am missing something really silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file with JSON data should look like below

```
{"queryID": "newId", "newCol": "newCol"}  
{"queryID": "newId", "newCol": "newCol"}
```

So it should be not just `JSON` but rather `newline delimited JSON`
See more about supported [JSON format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-formats#json_format)

Answer (score 1):

As a tip, you can convert your json file via [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to expected format.

```
jq -c '.[]' input.json > new.json
```

or

```
curl -s https://local/xx.json | jq -c '.[]'
```